# wxServerSocket with GUI?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

So I was following this tutorial: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2736

I understand everything up to these lines of code:

```
pServerSocket->SetEventHandler(*pHandler, ID_SERVER);

pHandler->Connect(ID_SERVER, wxEVT_SOCKET,
    (wxObjectEventFunction) &wxMyServer::OnServerEvent );
pHandler->Connect(ID_SOCKET, wxEVT_SOCKET,
    (wxObjectEventFunction) &wxMyServer::OnSocketEvent );
```

What are ID_SERVER and ID_SOCKET? Are they just an enum? Do I need to register them in an event table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDs are those associated with the socket objects using [wxSocket::SetEventHandler()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_socket_base.html#a09819e56d36638fb6b45bf3dd7ea8742) method. They are usually just members of an enum but you can use whatever (distinct) constants you want.

Finally, you register the event handlers *either* using the event tables *or* using `Connect()`. As you use the latter in this example, you don't need to use the event tables, it replaces them.